# Sending information with unnamed pipes

Tags: c, linux, pipe

My program have to send some bytes of information by using unnamed pipes.
I have a txt file named "input" which is supposed to be read by the program and it's information have to be send and write in another file named "output". Also i must use read(), write(), open() functions.
My code look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFSIZE 25

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    pid_t pid;
    int mypipefd[2];
    int ret;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int output;
    int stream;
    int nbytes;
    ret = pipe(mypipefd);

    if( ret == -1 ) {
        perror( "pipe error");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid = fork();

    if( pid == -1 ) {
        perror( "FORK ERROR...");
        exit(2);
    }
    if( pid == 0 ) {
        /* CHILD */
        printf(" Child process...\n");
        stream = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);
        if (close(mypipefd[0]) == -1 ) {
            perror("ERROR CLOSING PIPE");
            exit(3);
        }
        while ( (nbytes = read(stream, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0 ) {
            sleep(rand() %2);
            write(mypipefd[1], buf, nbytes );
        }
        if ( close(stream) == -1 ) {
        perror("ERROR CLOSING STREAM");
        exit(4);
        }
    }
    else {
        /* PARENT */
        printf(" Parent process...\n");
        output = open("output.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 00777);
        while ( (nbytes = read(mypipefd[0], buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0 ) {
            write(output, buf, nbytes);
        }
        printf("buf: %s\n", buf);
        if (close(output) == -1) {
            perror("ERROR CLOSING OUTPUT");
            exit(5);
        }
        if (close(mypipefd[1]) == -1 ) {
            perror("ERROR CLOSING PIPE");
            exit(6);
        }
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Unfortunately the code is not working [terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0SWn.png)

Before I tried while loop and was sending all the information at once, it worked, but output file looked like this [output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVljb.png)

while the input file look like this [input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6PF9.png)

Comment: In the child, do `close(mypipefd[1])` before exiting. Also, check the return on `write(mypipefd[1],buf,nbytes)` as pipes can return partial writes (i.e. you may need an inner loop inside your while loop). Also, parent should do `close(mypipefd[0])` after the read loop it. Then, parent should do `waitpid(pid,NULL,0)`

Answer (score 1):

The primary bug was that the *parent* must do `close(mypipefd[1])` *before* the parent read loop (and *not* after). This prevented the parent from seeing EOF on the pipe after the child was done writing.

Also, you were missing a `waitpid` in the parent.

The `printf` for `buf` in the parent was in the wrong place [after the read loop]. At that point, `buf` can't be guaranteed to have the correct data or that it's correctly zero-terminated. That's why stdout had some garbage chars at the end.

So, In addition to outputting to the output file, the loop should output to stdout, but should use `fwrite` as `buf` can't be guaranteed to be zero terminated.

I had missed that in my initial post, so I've corrected it.

As per my top comments, the child should loop on a [possible] partial write to  the pipe. I coded that.

Here's the version with the bugs annotated and fixed:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define BUFSIZE 25

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    pid_t pid;
    int mypipefd[2];
    int ret;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int output;
    int stream;
    int nbytes;

    ret = pipe(mypipefd);
    if( ret == -1 ) {
        perror( "pipe error");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if( pid == -1 ) {
        perror( "FORK ERROR...");
        exit(2);
    }

    if( pid == 0 ) {
        /* CHILD */
        printf(" Child process...\n");
        stream = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);
        if (close(mypipefd[0]) == -1 ) {
            perror("ERROR CLOSING PIPE");
            exit(3);
        }

        while ( (nbytes = read(stream, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0 ) {
            sleep(rand() %2);

#if 0
            write(mypipefd[1], buf, nbytes );
#else
            // NOTE: this _should_ work but adds extra at the end
            int off;
            int wlen;
            for (off = 0;  nbytes > 0;  off += wlen, nbytes -= wlen) {
                wlen = write(mypipefd[1], buf + off, nbytes );
                if (wlen <= 0)
                    break;
            }
#endif
        }

        if ( close(stream) == -1 ) {
        perror("ERROR CLOSING STREAM");
        exit(4);
        }

        // NOTE/FIX: child must close it's side of the pipe
#if 1
        close(mypipefd[1]);
#endif
    }

    else {
        /* PARENT */
        printf(" Parent process...\n");

        // NOTE/FIX: this must be closed _before_ the read loop -- holding it
        // open prevents parent from seeing EOF on pipe
#if 1
        if (close(mypipefd[1]) == -1 ) {
            perror("ERROR CLOSING PIPE");
            exit(6);
        }
#endif

#if 1
        printf("buf: ");
#endif

        output = open("output.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 00777);
        while ( (nbytes = read(mypipefd[0], buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0 ) {
            write(output, buf, nbytes);
#if 1
            fwrite(buf,1,nbytes,stdout);
#endif
        }

        // NOTE/BUG: the buffer at this point will only have the data from
        // the _last_ read and may not be null terminated
#if 0
        printf("buf: %s\n", buf);
#else
        printf("\n");
#endif

        if (close(output) == -1) {
            perror("ERROR CLOSING OUTPUT");
            exit(5);
        }

        // NOTE/BUG: this must be closed _before_ the parent's read loop
#if 0
        if (close(mypipefd[1]) == -1 ) {
            perror("ERROR CLOSING PIPE");
            exit(6);
        }
#endif

        // NOTE/FIX: this is missing (prevents orphan/zombie child process)
#if 1
        waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
#endif
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> but i don't understand what does "for" loop do here

A write to a pipe can generate a "short write" (e.g. you want to write 20 but the return value (i.e. number of bytes *actually* written) comes back with 15. You have to index into the buffer and write the remaining bytes in subsequent writes.

There is a kernel limit on how many bytes can be written in a single atomic write (e.g.) if you did `write(mypipefd[1],buf,10000000)`, the kernel doesn't have space allocated for such a large write, so it will return the value of what it could append to the pipe buffer [in the kernel].

Also, let's say the kernel pipe buffer can hold 64 bytes. And you write buffers of size 64 to it. Maybe the reader is reading only 32 bytes. So, the first write is fine. Then reader reads out 32 bytes. So, the next write to the pipe of 64, there is only space for 32 bytes, so the write will return 32

> Program have to display: "buf: This is ra" then "buf: ndom text"

Okay, I've fixed that

> At last, I need to implement error handling everywhere.

I've annotated places where I'd add error and handling, along with some things to look for.

Anyway, here's an updated version. I've left in the `// NOTE/*` comments but removed the `#if/#endif` pairs to make an easier read.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define BUFSIZE 25

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    pid_t pid;
    int mypipefd[2];
    int ret;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int output;
    int stream;
    int nbytes;

    ret = pipe(mypipefd);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("pipe error");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("FORK ERROR...");
        exit(2);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        /* CHILD */
        printf(" Child process...\n");
        stream = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);
        if (close(mypipefd[0]) == -1) {
            perror("ERROR CLOSING PIPE");
            exit(3);
        }

        while ((nbytes = read(stream, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0) {
            sleep(rand() % 2);

            // NOTE/FIX: writing to pipes _can_ generate a _short_ write. that
            // is, (e.g.) if the length given to write is 20, the return value
            // may be only 15. this means that the remaining 5 bytes must be
            // sent in a second/subsequent write
            int off;
            int wlen;
            for (off = 0;  nbytes > 0;  off += wlen, nbytes -= wlen) {
                wlen = write(mypipefd[1], buf + off, nbytes);
                if (wlen < 0) {
                    perror("ERROR WRITING TO FILE");
                    exit(3);
                }
                if (wlen == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (close(stream) == -1) {
            perror("ERROR CLOSING STREAM");
            exit(4);
        }

        // NOTE/FIX: child must close it's side of the pipe
        // NOTE/ERRCODE: check error code here
        close(mypipefd[1]);
    }

    else {
        /* PARENT */
        printf(" Parent process...\n");

        // NOTE/FIX: this must be closed _before_ the read loop -- holding it
        // open prevents parent from seeing EOF on pipe
        if (close(mypipefd[1]) == -1) {
            perror("ERROR CLOSING PIPE");
            exit(6);
        }

        // NOTE/ERRCODE: this should be checked for -1 (i.e. output file
        // could not be opened for file permission, etc. or other reasons
        // similar to those for the file write below)
        output = open("output.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 00777);

        // NOTE/FIX: we read one less than buffer size to allow for adding an
        // artificial zero byte at the end
        while ((nbytes = read(mypipefd[0], buf, BUFSIZE - 1)) > 0) {
            // NOTE/ERRCODE: error handling _could_ be added here but it would
            // be rare (e.g. filesystem has an I/O error because it's full or
            // marked R/O because of an I/O error on the underlying disk)
            write(output, buf, nbytes);

            // write partial buffer to stdout
            buf[nbytes] = 0;
            printf("buf: %s\n",buf);
        }

        if (close(output) == -1) {
            perror("ERROR CLOSING OUTPUT");
            exit(5);
        }

        // NOTE/FIX: this is missing (prevents orphan/zombie child process)
        // NOTE/ERRCODE: yes, this _can_ have an error return but here it's
        // unlikely because we _know_ that pid is valid
        // what can be done is to do:
        //   int status;
        //   waitpid(pid,&status,0)
        // then process the return code from the child using the W* macros
        // provided (e.g. WIFEXITED, WSTATUS) on status
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code works, but i don't understand what does "for" loop do here. Also I'd like to avoid 'fwrite()' function. Instead, I want the sending information to be displayed at every loop and it's length have to be dependent on 'BUFSIZE' defined. For example i have "This is random text" in my input file. Program have to display: "buf: This is ra" then "buf: ndom text". At last, I need to implement error handling everywhere. As far as I know, I still need it in 'write()' function between #if 0 and #else, also for 'close()' between #if 1 #endif, and for 'waitpid()'. Where else could I implement them?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added error handling everywhere, also I modified int main() to get argv[] and now I declare my input/output .txt files while opening program. Now I'm about to modify the program to use named pipes. I have to open FIFO pipe in the program and turn on producer/consumer processes there. So I tried to do that and this is what I did: `int fifo;
 mkfifo("fifo.fifo", 0666);` then in the child process `fifo = open("fifo.fifo", O_WRONLY);` and in parent process `fifo = open("fifo.fifo", O_RDONLY);` and `unlink("fifo.fifo");` at the end. Program stops  at "ERROR CLOSING PIPE"